# How to UNPIVOT an aliased query result using PHP and MySql

Tags: mysql, query, php, alias, unpivot

I would be grateful for your assistance in helping me get solution for my project weather query problem. I have arrived at the query below and is working:

");
$first_row = true;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($first_row) {
        $first_row = false;
        // Output header row from keys.
        echo '';
        foreach($row as $key => $field) {
            echo '' . htmlspecialchars($key) . '';
        }
        echo '';
    }
    echo '';
    foreach($row as $key => $field) {
        echo '' . htmlspecialchars($field) . '';
    }
    echo '';
}
echo("");
?>

The output has a long row of heading columns and I want to UNPIVOT the result of above query:

R.weatherID    R.Days    R.locationID    R.windDirection    R1.weatherID    R1.Days    R1.locationID    R1.windDirection    R2.weatherID    R2.Days    R1.locationID    R2.windDirection

and get the short output format below:

R.weatherID    R.Days    R.locationID    R.windDirection
R1.weatherID    R1.Days    R1.locationID    R1.windDirection
R2.weatherID    R2.Days    R1.locationID    R2.windDirection

Thank you very much for your time.

### EDIT:
-- Changed R2.Days = (R2.Days + 1) - 5 to
-- R1.Days = (R2.Days + 1) - 5
-- implies is there a similar pattern five days from this record

### -- Table structure for table `R`

### CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `R` (
W_id INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
weatherID VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
Days INT(6) NOT NULL,
locationID VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
windDirection VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (W_id)
);

### -- Index for table `R`

ALTER TABLE `R`
ADD UNIQUE KEY `uDW` (`Days`,`W_id`);

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so I can see if the datatypes are amenable to `(R2.Days + 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `UNION` instead of `JOIN`:

```
SELECT  R.weatherID, R.Days, R.locationID, R.timeRecorded, R.windDirection,
        R1.weatherID, R1.Days, R1.locationID, R1.timeRecorded,
        R1.windDirection, R2.weatherID, R2.Days, R2.locationID,
        R2.timeRecorded, R2.windDirection
    FROM  R
    WHERE  R.windDirection IN ("NW'', "SW", "SE", "N", "W" )
 UNION 
 SELECT  R.weatherID, R.Days, R.locationID, R.timeRecorded, R.windDirection,
        R1.weatherID, R1.Days, R1.locationID, R1.timeRecorded,
        R1.windDirection, R2.weatherID, R2.Days, R2.locationID,
        R2.timeRecorded, R2.windDirection
    FROM  R AS R1
    WHERE  R1.windDirection IN ("NW'', "SW", "SE", "N", "W" )
```

Since I don't understand the intent of `ON R2.Days = (R2.Days + 1) - 5`, I don't know how to add R2 on.